# Counting sort not working as expected

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to implement counting sort as given the CLRS book. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void counting_sort(int numbers[], int k, int len)
{
    int *temp = malloc(k*sizeof(int));
    int *res = malloc(len*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp[numbers[i]]++;
    }

    for(i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        temp[i] += temp[i-1];
    }


    int j;
    for(i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        res[temp[numbers[i]]] = numbers[i];
        temp[numbers[i]]--;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
        printf("%d ", res[j]);
    printf("\n");


    free(temp);
    free(res);
}

void main()
{
    int numbers[] = {2, 5, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3};
    counting_sort(numbers, 6, 8);
}
```

But the output I get is: `0 0 0 2 2 3 3 3`. The output is almost correct, I should get `0 0 2 2 3 3 3 5`.

Any idea what is wrong? I have a feeling it's the last loop that's messing it up.

Comment: This is tagged as C++, so you don't need to "malloc()."

Comment: Have you used the debugger to debug your code?

Comment: @EvanCarslake, sorry I added c++ tag instead of c tag by mistake. I update the tag and it should reflect shortly

Comment: Unrelated: the name of your function is somewhat odd from the caller's perspective, since after it is executed exactly nothing is actually sorted (i.e. `numbers` remains unchanged on the caller-side). If you do actually sort the input buffer *and* retain the sorted output, the `res` buffer is not needed, just fyi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
res[temp[numbers[i]]] = numbers[i];
```

changed it to this:

```
res[temp[numbers[i]]-1] = numbers[i];
```

It seem to work fine.